# Angular 12 error '"ng2-charts"' has no exported member named 'ChartsModule'

Tags: angular

I get the above error when trying to add the ChartsModule to my app.module.ts file.

I added the charts to my project using the ng command all the articles say to use:

npm install ng2-charts chart.js --save

My app.module.ts file looks like the following.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like charts library has had a new release and they replaced ChartsModule with NgChartsModule.

Try to:

```
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
```

And use it as you would use `ChartsModule` ( ofcourse there might be some other changes ).

Or you can downgrade and install not latest charts.js.

Here, even their GitHub ( https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts )
Says:

Import the `NgChartsModule` in your app main module:

```
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

// In your App's module:
imports: [
  NgChartsModule
]
```

Answer (score 1):

So in your app.module.ts file while importing charts use this below import statement.

```js
import {NgChartsModule} from 'ng2-charts';
```

After that in the same app.module.ts file in the imports section use as below :

```js
imports : [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  NgChartsModule
  ]
```

```
 Now your NgChartsModule will work
```